# Upgrading Laravel in a monolothic Laravel + Inertia's + Vue3 app. Must I upgrade inertiajs too?

Tags: laravel, webpack, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

I have an application made with Laravel 8 + Inertia + Vue 3, and everything is working pretty well.

My situation is that I need to upgrade Laravel to v10 without modifying anything on the frontend side. I used Composer to upgrade Laravel, and everything in the backend (which doesn't use Vue) is working as expected.

However, the frontend is not loading the Vue.js app. The index page is blank, and the source code contains the correct tags with `<div id="app" data-page="Same information that in working app"></div>`.

I have verified that Laravel has switched from Webpack to Vite, and that Inertia is on v1, which has some breaking changes. Therefore, I am trying to temporarily avoid upgrading Inertia unless absolutely necessary.

Is there a way to achieve it or must I do a full upgrade?